# min_doc_count term aggregation returns result with sum_other_doc_count > 0 but no buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, bucket, elasticsearch-aggregation

Running this search in kibana:

```
GET myindex/mytype/_search
{"size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myfield",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Gives:

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 12,
    "successful": 12,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 46117,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 12,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 45817,
      "buckets": []
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this result. Per the [term aggregation documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) `sum_other_doc_count` means:

> when there are lots of unique terms, Elasticsearch only returns the top terms; this number is the sum of the document counts for all buckets that are not part of the response

Since there are no buckets in the response, it seems odd that there are apparently buckets that were not included. Does `sum_other_doc_count` include the buckets that were excluded by `min_doc_count`, and therefore the result can be interpreted as meaning there were no documents with duplicates for `myfield`?

If the latter is the case, assuming there *were* buckets returned, is is possible to get a `some_other_doc_count` that does not include the `min_doc_count` excluded buckets, or a total count of the buckets?

**Update**:
It seems that I can get some of the information I want via a cardinality aggregation. Total records - field cardinality provides the approximate number of documents with a duplicate field.

Comment: any way to prevent the results with empty buckets from being included in the response? if there are lots of docs with no dups (in a sub-agg), it's hard to find those with 2+.